# Make the Home and End keys in Aptana 3 on OS X go to start/end of line rather than start/end of file

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, aptana-studio

I recently discovered that the Mac has a lovely tendency to treat the Home and End keys on a 105-key keyboard as instructions to go to the start or end of the entire file, respectively.

I did some searching across Stack Exchange a while ago and found some tips that helped (sorry can't remember what they were now).  Some applications now behave sensibly.

BUT when using Aptana Studio 3 these keys still persistently jump to the start or end of file.  Since I've been using these keys for decades to go to the start or the end of the line, I press them a lot and then proceed to swear loudly.

I'd **love** a system-wide fix that works consistently but I'll be happy if anyone can point me to a fix for Aptana as that's where it hurts the most.

Comment: You probably just modified [DefaultKeyBinding.dict](http://blog.macromates.com/2005/key-bindings-for-switchers/) before, right? It's relatively system-wide, but the custom keybindings aren't supported by some cross-platform apps.

Comment: not really sure @Lri but that does fit with what I've observed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Preferences > General > Keys`.

In there you will find all keybindings specific to the Aptana environment.  To change the Home and End keys to line start/end rather the file start/end, search for "File Start" (or "Text Start") and "File End" (or "Text End") and unbind the keys then search for "Line Start" and "Line End" to setup the new bindings.

Comment: thankyou @slhck for removing gmy confession that I thought of the answer to my own question mere moments after asking it

Comment: Please check my edit if the labels are correct, another user said they were different.

Comment: the labels seem right